# Export data from a table to a .csv file with a checkbox using php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to export data from a table marked in a checkbox to a .csv file but everytime I export the data is exported twice the same as the table headers. I hope you can help me. I am sure I am missing something in the code.

```
//get records from database
$idusuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
$datos = $mysqli->query("select * from partidas");

if( !isset($_POST['casilla']) OR !is_array($_POST['casilla']) ) {
    exit('No se ha seleccionado ningun dato para la exportacion');
}
    
$delimiter = ",";
$filename = "Partidas_Abiertas" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";

//create a file pointer
$f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
   
//creaa los encabezados de las columnas
$fields = array('Cuenta', 'NombreCliente', 'KZz','zv', 'Doc.Factura', 'Fecha_Factura','Venc.Neto', 'Importe_en_ML', 'texto');
fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);


//extrae cada fila de datos, les da formato csv y los escribe en fichero creado
foreach ($_POST['casilla'] as $value) {

    $value="Select * from partidas where id_partida = $value LIMIT 1"; 
    $result = $mysqli->query($value);

    while($d = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $lineData = array($d[cuenta], $d[nCliente], $d[kzz], $d[zv],  $d[docFac], $d[fechaDoc], $d[vencNeto], $d[importe], $d[texto]);
        fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter);
    }

    //vuelve al principio de cada fila
    fseek($f, 0);

    //crea las cabeceras para la exportacion para descarga del archivo con el nombre y fecha
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');


    //Escribe toda la informacion restante de un puntero a un archivo 
    fpassthru($f);
}
exit;
?>
```

This is the HTML

```
<p>Resultados <?php echo $datos->num_rows; ?></p>
        
        <div class="row table-responsive">
            <!---Exportar lo marcado en la tabla a csv-----> 
                   <form method="post" action="exportarPartidas.php" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " name="export" value="CSV Export marcado" target="_blank">
                                
                        </div></br> 
            
        <table  class="table display table-striped table-bordered" id="mitabla" border="1" style="width:100%" >
    
            <thead style='background-color:#A0A0A0;'>
            <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Marcar para exportar</th>
            <th align="center"><font color=#070707>N&#186; Cuenta</th>
            <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Nombre de Cliente</th>
            <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Abreviatura (Kzz)</th>
            <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Zona de Ventas</th>
            <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Doc.Fact.</th>
            <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Fecha Factura</th>
            <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Venc. Neto</th>
            <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Importe en ML</th>
            <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Texto</th>
            </thead>
    
        <?php while($d= $datos->fetch_object()):?>
            <tr>
            <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="casilla[]" value="<?php echo $d-> id_partida;?>"></td>
            <td align="left"><?php echo $d->cuenta; ?></td>
            <td align="left"><?php echo $d->nCliente;?></td>
            <td align="left"><?php echo $d->kzz;?></td>
            <td align="left"><?php echo $d->zv; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $d->docFac; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $d->fechaDoc; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $d->vencNeto; ?></td>
            <td align="left"><?php echo $d->importe; ?></td>
            <td align="left"><?php echo $d->texto; ?></td>
        
            </tr>
    
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </table>
      </form>  
            <?php else:?>
                <h3>No hay Datos</h3>
            <?php endif; ?>
    
        </div>
```

And this is the result in the csv file. For this example I have checked 3 columns[csv file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ispzr.png)

Comment: Side note: `$datos = $mysqli->query("select * from partidas");` is not being used, you should remove this unnecessary call to the database.

Comment: Anyway there's nothing here which would cause the data to be output twice into the CSV. The most likely reasons could be a) $_POST["casilla"] contains the same data twice, or b) the client-side is making two identical requests to the server. What debugging have you done? have you checked what's actually being sent? Obviously we can't see your client-side code so we can't see what it might do.

Comment: I have added html code and examplo o csv file to the post. SO you can see it

Comment: Ok thankyou, that's helpful. I might have been wrong in my first comment a little but but I'm not sure. What happens if you remove the `fseek($f, 0);` line?

Comment: it doesn´t print anything. The file is empty if I delete that line.

Comment: Ok I edited your question to indent the code properly. Now it's clearer. It looks to me like your `foreach` should end before the `fseek` command. Otherwise it's going to repeatedly return to the beginning of the file and output it again. Sorry I didn't see that earlier because it wasn't clear due to the mis-alignment of the brackets in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logical error in the code.

Your `foreach` loop needs to end before the `fseek` command. Otherwise, for every value in the "casilla" array it will return to the start of the data and output all of it again.

It should be like this:

```
//extrae cada fila de datos, les da formato csv y los escribe en fichero creado
foreach ($_POST['casilla'] as $value) {

    $value="Select * from partidas where id_partida = $value LIMIT 1"; 
    $result = $mysqli->query($value);

    while($d = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $lineData = array($d[cuenta], $d[nCliente], $d[kzz], $d[zv],  $d[docFac], $d[fechaDoc], $d[vencNeto], $d[importe], $d[texto]);
        fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter);
    }
}
//vuelve al principio de cada fila
fseek($f, 0);

//crea las cabeceras para la exportacion para descarga del archivo con el nombre y fecha
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');


//Escribe toda la informacion restante de un puntero a un archivo 
fpassthru($f);
```